# GatewayIntentBits is not defined - Discord Bot - guildID

Tags: python

I am currently coding my first Discord Bot but keep getting this issue: GatewayIntentBits is not defined

I am currently coding my first Discord Bot and wrote this:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds
    ]
})

const guildId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

but I keep getting this error: GatewayIntentBits is not defined

All code:
const Discord = require("discord.js")

```
require("dotenv").config()

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds
]
})

let bot = {
    client
}

const Guilds = "1079351793550643352"

client.slashcommands = new Discord.Collection()

client.loadSlashCommands = (bot, reload) =>     require("./handlers/slashcommands")
client.loadSlashCommands(bot, false)

client.on("ready", async () => {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
    if (!guild)
        return console.error("Target guild not found")

    await guild.commands.set([...client.slashcommands.values()])
    console.log(`Successfully loaded in ${client.slashcommands.size}`)
    process.exit(0)
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Comment: Try importing it using `require`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily fix the error by importing `GatewayIntentBits` before it. You can do that using `require`, a built-in method.

```js
const {  GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
```

Seeing that you also import `Discord`, you can import them both in the same line

```js
const {  GatewayIntentBits, Discord } = require("discord.js");
```

Comment: It now says:  Cannot access 'GatewayIntentBits' before initialization

Comment: @Barnaby You need to put it on the first line of the code